# VBA code to copy command buttons

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'm stumped.  Please help.  What VBA code can be used to copy command buttons from one slide to another (along with the code behind them)?  I think I can handle the looping, but I can't find the code/line/command that will do the actual copying.  Thanks!

Comment: Would it be an option to put the button on the slide master to have it available on all slides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a VBA macro to copy all buttons from one slide to another:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub copyButtons(sourceSlide As Slide, targetSlide As Slide)
    Dim shp As Shape

    If sourceSlide.Name <> targetSlide.Name Then
        For Each shp In sourceSlide.Shapes
            If InStr(shp.Name, "Button") > 0 Then
                shp.Copy
                targetSlide.Shapes.Paste
            End If
        Next shp
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub testCopyButtons()
    Dim sourceSlide As Slide
    Dim targetSlide As Slide

    Set sourceSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(2)
    Set targetSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(3)
    Call copyButtons(sourceSlide, targetSlide)
End Sub
```

The copied buttons will inherit the links and actions from the original buttons.